# Arc Length and the business of backtracking

Tags: calculus, physics

Provided some parameterized curve in space along which a particle travels in time, such as $\vec{r}(t) = (x(t), y(t))$.  Does the arc length formula take into account the fact that the particle may or may not backtrack.

i.e. does $\int_{0}^{t} |\vec{r}\prime(t)| ds$ give the length of the curve or the distance the particle traveled, which may be longer than the length of the curve (if the particle is able to backtrack).

It seems to me since $|\vec{r}\prime (t)|$ is the speed of the particle at time t, that this would be the distance the particle traveled including the backtracking.  How then, would I obtain a pure length of the curve itself?

Comment: In general it gives the distance travelled, not the length of the curve . If $r'(t)$ is never $0,$ there can be no backtracking, but there could still be repeating (as in the case of going around a circle). So if you want the length of the curve traced out, you have to look at the specific case at hand and deal with it. Do you have an example?

Comment: it gives the length of the the curve

Comment: The simplest way is just to pick a path that doesn't backtrack. One could also choose to only measure distance traveled when the particle is moving 'forward', but for a generic curve I don't know a good way to define that.

Comment: In simple harmonic motion the particle travels either way, most of the time time cancelling distance traveled due to changing sign of velocity. The displacement graph oscillates, but does not monotonously increase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example showing that the integral gives the **total** distance traveled. Consider the line integral along the line segment in the real plane from the origin to $(1,1)$. From $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$, you have $\vec{r}(t)=\langle t,t\rangle$ with $t\in[0,1]$. In the reverse direction, you would have $\vec{r}(t)=\langle 1-t,1-t\rangle$ with $t\in[0,1]$ and the particle starts at $(1,1)$ and travels to $(0,0)$. I'll denote the first path by $\mathcal{C}$ and its reverse by $-\mathcal{C}$.

Compute the line integral:
$$\int\limits_\mathcal{C}\,\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int_0^1\sqrt{1^2+1^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sqrt2$$
And in the reverse direction,
$$\int\limits_\mathcal{-C}\,\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int_0^1\sqrt{(-1)^2+(-1)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\sqrt2$$
Now consider both paths taken at the same time, so the particle starts at the origin, travels to $(1,1)$, then backtracks and returns to the origin. This compound path (which I denote by $\mathcal{C}+(-\mathcal{C})$) can be parameterized by $\vec{r}(t)=\left\langle 1-2\left|\frac{1}{2}-t\right|,1-2\left|\frac{1}{2}-t\right|\right\rangle$ with $t\in[0,1]$. The distance traveled is then
$$\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}+(-\mathcal{C})}\,\mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int_0^{1/2}\sqrt{2^2+2^2}\,\mathrm{d}t+\int_{1/2}^1\sqrt{(-2)^2+(-2)^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=2\sqrt2$$
whereas you would intuitively expect the **net** distance traveled to be $0$. The notion of "arc length" would have to be carefully defined - does it refer to the net or total distance?

To summarize: If the particle does not change direction, then the net and total distances are the same. If it does change direction, then the net and total are different, and you need to specify which of these is equivalent to the length of the path.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification.